# Flutter PageView not swipeable on web (desktop mode)

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview

I'm new to flutter.
I implemented flutter PageView with the help of its documents:

```
/// Flutter code sample for PageView

// Here is an example of [PageView]. It creates a centered [Text] in each of the three pages
// which scroll horizontally.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PageController controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);
    return PageView(
      /// [PageView.scrollDirection] defaults to [Axis.horizontal].
      /// Use [Axis.vertical] to scroll vertically.
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      controller: controller,
      children: const <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Text('First Page'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Second Page'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Third Page'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And I run it on Android, it works well.
and It works also in web (mobile mode).

But when I run it on chrome (web|desktop) pages are not swipeable, and there is no way to change pages.

How to enable swipe on web desktop export?

Flutter version is 2.5.2

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Thanks to Bigfoot, For support swipe with mouse, we need to change default scroll behavior of app by these steps:

1- Create a class, extend it from `MaterialScrollBeavior`, and override `dragDevices`:

```
class AppScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
      };
}
```

2- Pass an AppScrollBehavior instance to scrollBehavior property of MaterialApp:

```
MaterialApp(
      scrollBehavior: AppScrollBehavior(),
      ...
    );
```

After that, we can swipe between pages also with mouse.

**Update Flutter 3.3:**

From flutter 3.3, trackpad on laptops not working for scroll and swipe actions, if you need to support trackpad too, you need add `PointerDeviceKind.trackpad` to dragDevices like this:

```
class AppScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
        PointerDeviceKind.trackpad,
      };
}
```

Comment: You can also override the `scrollBehavior` of `PageView` directly

Comment: Indeed: 
PageView(
                scrollBehavior: const ScrollBehavior().copyWith(dragDevices: {
                  PointerDeviceKind.touch,
                  PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
                  PointerDeviceKind.stylus,
                }),

Answer (score 8):

on flutter 2.5.0 they change the scroll behavior
check this [Default drag scrolling devices](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/default-scroll-behavior-drag)

Answer (score 6):

Without creating additional classes and other stuff, you can do this:

```dart
ScrollConfiguration(
        behavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(
          dragDevices: {
            PointerDeviceKind.touch,
            PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
          },
        ),
        child: MyScrollableWidget(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

I used PageView in my Flutter portfolio website. I noticed that I couldn't swipe to change pages. Later I came to know that this could be done by my Mac's trackpad gestures.
Since the PageView was horizontal, I had to horizontally swipe two fingers on my trackpad. You can try that.